# Which is the right place to store data for a wizard-like application?

Tags: android, architecture, storage

my application consists of < 10 activities, which cover the wizard part. Each of these activities should collect user data and save the current status, which should be resumed, if the application is unexpectedly terminated.

Now, as the collected data seems to be 'private', the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) suggests three possibilities to save data:

1. **Shared Preferences**
   Seems appropriate for my purpose; key/value would be perfectly fine for my kind of data
2. **Internal Storage**
   Imo an I/O on every intent is an overkill
3. **SQLite Database**
   Fine, too

The thing I'm curious about now, is this the right approach to choose a home for my data? Are there any guidelines or best practices concerning storage on Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preferences uses IO - as it just an xml file in data folder of your application. Choose the one which simplier for you to implement. I would use Shared Preferences.

As for "home for data" - it is ok. The storage possibilities are already well-designed for you, so you shouldn't be worry about it. Just use the one which fits your purposes the best.